# find and rm with exclude from list of names that include square brackets

Tags: bash, find

I need to delete non-empty directories, but exclude some based on a list. that list has some special characters, particularly `[` and `]`. I can modify the list to escape the characters as necessary, but nothing i do makes them match.

My command that only works with simple names is:

```
find /dir $(printf "! -name %s " $(cat skip_files)) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

and my `skip_files` list would be:

```
dir with [ab] in.the.name
dir with [a] in.the.name
slightly complex
simplename
```

I have tried `\` and `\\` to no avail along with `"` even for the `slightly complex` name.

If I test the command without the list, it works with escaped `[` and `]` as expected.

```
find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "dir with \[a\] in.the.name"
```

I am using bash on debian 9.
`find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git`

Comment: You didn't mention which shell you're using. I tagged it `bash` on the assumption that if you don't know which shell you're using, it's probably bash.

Comment: yes, i'm using bash, but can use others

Comment: Use regex instead of name

Comment: Use `printf "! -name '%s' "` single-quoting the name. And don't `$(cat skip_files)` that is an Unnecessary Use of `cat` (a *UUOc*), simply `$(< skip_files)`, redirection doesn't spawn a separate subshell. If that doesn't handled the contents of `skip_files` (for whatever reason), you can look at some of the more extreme quoting or escaping solutions.

Comment: single quoting seems to ignore the whole list. double quoting has the same effect as not quoting. using `< skip_files` works, but it doesn't solve my problem. what are the more "extreme quoting or escaping solutions" that you mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily change the field splitters `$IFS` to handle each line as a whole field at a time. However, that doesn't get around the fact that glob-expansion still happens, which affects the `[]` brackets too, and `\` doesn't help.

```
(
    IFS=$'\n'
    find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
        $(printf '!\n-name\n%s\n' $(<skip_files)) -exec rm -rf {} +
)
```

---

Alternately, you could `grep` for each filename. This is safe but slower.

```
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -exec /bin/sh -c 'grep -F -x "$(basename "$1")" skip_files' - {} \;
    -o -exec rm -rf {} +
```

`-F` means the filename is a fixed string, not a regex; `-x` means it must match the whole line.

If you change the format of `skip_files` so that it includes the whole path (e.g. `/dir/dir with [ab] in.the.name`), you don't need the extra shell process.

```
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -exec grep -F -x {} skip_files \; -o -exec rm -rf {} +
```

---

Finally, you could construct the command line more carefully with Bash arrays.

```
tests=()
while IFS= read -r name; do
    tests+=('!' -name "${name}")
done <skip_files
find /dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth -1 "${tests[@]}" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Here, `$IFS` is temporarily set to empty so that `read` doesn't strip out leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: using the whole path in the skip file with grep works great. thanks!

Comment: @jakethedog Good to hear! I forgot one thing when I was writing this: you can add `-q` as an option to `grep`, if you don't want it to print anything to the terminal.